# Loading XML into flash

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2

I have an unusual problem which apear when I moved my files to another hosting (in old one was everything ok).

I have main flash site and swf loaded into it.
My main flash can read and parse xml's, but swf loaded into main flash can't read any xml.

I'm 100% sure that path to xml is correct. I can send information to PHP file to save some data in xml and this data is stored in xml. I can get informations from PHP, but I can't get any xml data...
It looks like server side problem.

Is there anything what I could overlooked?

---

### EDIT

I have found the problem. When I moved files to another server, there was a **.htaccess** file with lines:

```
<FilesMatch ".*xml">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>
```

In old hosting, all code in this file is commented (I don't know what does it depend on). Anyway.

Comment: from where are you getting this xml? Is this XML all in memory?

Comment: All the files are stored in one server, on one domain.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the domain where the XML is hosted has an appropriate [crossdomain.xml file](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html). Also have a look at `System.security.allowDomain` and try allowing the domain in either the parent or children SWF (or both).

Without any error message, it's difficult to provide more help.

Comment: The error I get (from firefox console) is: "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden". I don't realy know **if System.security.allowDomain** is in this case needed, because all the files are stored in one place. Also crossdomain.xml file is located in root of my site.